# Download log files from FTP Server using a keyword in python

Tags: python-3.x, ftp, ftplib

I have a problem in getting a log files from FTP Server.
I can get a single file from FTP Server. But I'm having a problem in getting multiple files and can't get files from it.

In my FTP Server I have log files with format like this `LOG_NAME_DATETIME`

Here are the example of my files in FTP Server.

```
log_sample_01-02-2018_08:00:20:119203.txt
log_sample_01-02-2018_19:00:40:113203.txt
log_sample_01-02-2018_22:00:15:112203.txt
```

The only difference in my log files are the `time` and I want to download them by `date`

This is what I tried in my program and got an error.

```
name = 'sample'
date = '01-02-2018'
ftp.retrbinary('RETR log_' + name + '_' + date + '*.txt', open('log.txt', 'wb').write)
```

I thought the `*` at the end part will do it since in linux command line, I used `cat * .txt` in concatenating my logs. Already tried to search some reference about my problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: @StephenRauch Hello, Thank you for your comment. I tried to edit it :)

Comment: One of the fundamentals of an MCVE, is that someone can copy and paste it, and it will run.  This is NOT an MCVE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably have to filter the files to download on the client machine.
You can list the existing files:

```
fileNames = ftp.nlst()
```

And download the ones you want based on their names:

```
for fileName in fileNames:
    currentName, currentDate, currentTime = fileName.split("_")
    if currentName == name and currentDate == date:
        ftp.retrbinary('RETR '+fileName, open('log.txt', 'wb').write)
```

You might have to add a `.rstrip("\n")` to `fileName` in the last line if the the endline (or `\n` in unix) at the end of the file names cause problem.

Note that this exact syntax does not work if there is an underscore in your file name.

Inspired by [this github file](https://gist.github.com/nasrulhazim/cfd5f01e3b261b09d54f721cc1a7c50d).

Comment: Hello sir, thank you for your answer. I'm finding a way how to do it with a filename like this? `log-server.net-SAMPLE-01-01-02-2018_22:00:15:112203.txt`

Comment: In this case you can use the code example with `name = "log-server.net-SAMPLE-01-"` and `date = "01-02-2018"`. I also updated my example because it was wrong...